# Azure not supporting reflection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I uploaded an ASP.NET MVC site to Azure, which works just fine in the emulator. When I run it on Azure however I get the error "Method not found: 'System.Object System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue(System.Object)'"

Stack Trace:

```
[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Object System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue(System.Object)'.]
   FW.Helpers.ListHelper.ToSelectListItemModels(IEnumerable`1 list, Expression`1 valueProperty, Expression`1 textProperty) +0
   My.Application.MyBuilderService.GetFilterList() +1444
   My.Application.MyBuilderService.BuildMyViewModel(Query query) +547
   My.Appsite.Controllers.MyController.BuildMyViewModel(Query query) in C:\Users\user\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsAzureProject3\MvcWebRole1\Controllers    \MyController.cs:40
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +248
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
           System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +125
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +640
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor,     IDictionary`2 parameters) +312
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +691
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +162
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +305
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +20
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +469
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: Found the error. I was using a library that used some .NET 4.5 preview stuff.

Comment: Is your web role running with Full Trust?

Comment: Glad you found the error. You fixed it...how?

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal Windows and .NET installation.  Reflection is supported.  Clearly there is another factor here.  We don't have enough information to help however.  A stack trace is important for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to make sure the DLLs you use all have the **Copy Local** property set to True.  Like:
http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-2-and-windows-azure/

Comment: I tried setting Copy Local to True for all DLLs. It did not help.